# iOS App Signup Error

Tags: ios, authentication, afnetworking

I receive this error when I tried to signup an account with the app im building. May I know what does this error means? Thank you!

```
BaseNetworkManager.m:164 Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 
"Expected status code in (200-299), got 500" UserInfo=0x16d30560 
{NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; 
url =websitelink.error.html" 


AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey=NSMutableURLRequest: 0x16670d80> { URL: mywebsite/users.json }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=h mywebsite.com/users.json, NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299), got 500, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x1669fe20> { URL: mywebsite.com/users.json } { status code: 500, headers {
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 690;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Fri, 01 May 2015 12:37:44 GMT";
    Server = Cowboy;
    Status = "500 Internal Server Error";
    Via = "1.1 vegur";
    "X-Rack-Cache" = "invalidate, pass";
    "X-Request-Id" = "tyud";
    "X-Runtime" = "5.087065"; } }} 
2015-05-01 20:37:45.002 appname[1677:60b] <BaseNetworkManager.m:165> (null)
```

Comment: the error message actually says it all. you need to actually ask a question.

Comment: Hi Micheal, I think i didn't written it properly. I have update my question. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server is telling you

```
500 Internal Server Error
```

this means that the server has a problem that is not your fault. (unless you are the one who is responsible for the server.)

HTTP 200..299 means "ok"
HTTP 300..399 means "look somewhere else"
HTTP 400..499 means "there is a problem with your request." for example 404=file not found, 403=forbidden, etc.
**HTTP 500..599 means "the server has a problem / is misconfigured"**

see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html for more info.